# How to check all data load befere load add new row in to the grid(ExtJS 3.2)

Tags: extjs3

I have a Editable grid i want auto load roweditor and set some value in that column. So i write a funcation call RowAdd()

```
RowAdd = function(){
      var grid = this.gridPtnr;
      var ds = grid.getStore();
      var roweditor = Ext.getCmp(grid.getId() + "_roweditor");
      var dt = new Date();
      var rec = new ds.recordType({ }, "new" + dt.format('U'));
      rec.set('USER_ID', '<?php echo $user_id; ?>');
      rec.set('COUNTRY_ID', '<?php echo $county_id; ?>');
      ds.insert(0, rec);
      grid.getView().refresh();
      grid.getSelectionModel().selectRow(0);
      roweditor.startEditing(0);
}
```

some how this method gave to me error because not load Grid data when i try to add new row in to the grid. but i added delay time before the `ds.insert(0, rec);` line that work correctly. Delay is not perfect solution for me that is not depended on client PC. Anyone know how to add row after the grid data fully loaded please help to me.

Comment: when i add alert before `ds.insert(0, rec);` line that work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is Store don't have data when i try to insert record So i can insert data after the store is fully load

```
RowAdd = function(){
      var grid = this.gridPtnr;
      var ds = grid.getStore();
      var roweditor = Ext.getCmp(grid.getId() + "_roweditor");
      var dt = new Date();
      var rec = new ds.recordType({ }, "new" + dt.format('U'));
      rec.set('USER_ID', '<?php echo $user_id; ?>');
      rec.set('COUNTRY_ID', '<?php echo $county_id; ?>');
      ds.load({
         callback : function(r, options, success) {
                     ds.insert(0, rec);
                     grid.getView().refresh();
                     grid.getSelectionModel().selectRow(0);
                     roweditor.startEditing(0);
                    }
      });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use new `store.recordType` to create a new Records of the type held in the Store and use `store.insert` method to add newly created record. Below is a code snippet

```
var recordData = {
    colum1: 0,
    colum2: 'string data',
    colum3: 0
};
var recId = 3; // provide unique id
var p = new store.recordType(recordData, recId); // create new record
grid.stopEditing();
store.insert(0, p); // insert a new record into the store (also see add)
grid.startEditing(0, 0);
```